# Elasticsearch doesn't work after create repository No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>'

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hello I have problem with Spring Data ElasticSearch I can connect with elasticSearch but after create repository my program stop working this is my code. Thank you in advance for your help with solve this problem

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.storyworld.repository.elastic")
public class ElasticSearchConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_ELASTIC_HOST = "localhost";
private static final int PROPERTY_ELASTIC_PORT = 9300;
private static final String PROPERTY_ELASTIC_CLUSTER_NAME = "elasticsearch";

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}

@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {
    Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", PROPERTY_ELASTIC_CLUSTER_NAME).build();

    return TransportClient.builder().settings(esSettings).build().addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(PROPERTY_ELASTIC_HOST), PROPERTY_ELASTIC_PORT));
}

}
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface ChatRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Chat, String>{}
```

and class Chat:

```
@Document(indexName = "chatest", type = "chat")
public class Chat {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String message;
}
```

After create Repository I got error:

```
479 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'chatRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596) [catalina.jar:8.5.6-dev]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805) [catalina.jar:8.5.6-dev]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
```

I think this issue occurs because JPARepository this is config for JPA

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.storyworld.repository.sql")
public class MySQLConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "root";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storyworld?useSSL=false";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "root";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "com.storyworld.domain.sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_AUTO = "update";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_AUTO);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , might be because of dependencies conflict , because common dependency shared by Spring data elastic search and spring data JPA .

I am using this code  , try with that . I am sure it will solve your issue :-

```
<!-- Spring ElasticSearch Data JPA-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring  Data JPA-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After changed version of spring-data-elasticsearch to 2.0.1.RELEASE and remove all old repositories everything works properly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to add @Repository to your interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still same issue occurs